# Split a string by a pattern in Python (not at the start or end)

Tags: python, regex, split

I'm trying to split a string when there is an occurrence of a hyphen and a digit together in Python.

Example -

```
'ABC7-8-1234: Veggie - RESTRICTED (1)' -> ['ABC7','234: Veggie - RESTRICTED (1)']
'AB-WALT-9-2065: Application (6)` -> ['AB-WALT', '065: Application (6)']
```

As Step 1 - I tried re.split() to split by '-'. but it's not working.

```
    name = re.split(r"\B-", string)
```

I get `['ABC7-8-1234: Veggie ', ' RESTRICTED (1)']` as the output instead of `['ABC7','8','1234: Veggie ', ' RESTRICTED (1)']`.

Step 2 would be checking the occurrence of both hyphen and digit. like -[0-9]

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Try replacing that `\B` with a `\d`. `\d` captures a digit.

Comment: `re.split('-\d-', st)` will give you `['ABC7', '1234: Veggie - RESTRICTED (1)']` as output. There you can find a way to keep just what you need

Comment: Is there always a colon after the strings you want to split?

Comment: @JuanC Yes there is always a colon.

Comment: In fact, it is not clear the expected output. What is the meaning of `->` in your example?

Comment: @JuanC I think your answer works for me. I'm only interested in the very first element. `'ABC7'` in this case.

Comment: re.split("-\d",string) should help you

Answer (score 0):

For a full answer:

```
st='ABC7-8-1234: Veggie - RESTRICTED (1)'
st=re.search('(.*):.*', st).group(1)
re.split('-\d-', st)

Out[26]: ['ABC7', '1234']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first split your string with `:` and take zeroth index and then split that string using regex `-\d+-` and you should get your desired values as you posted in your question. See this Python code,

```
import re

arr = ['ABC7-8-1234: Veggie - RESTRICTED (1)', 'AB-WALT-9-2065: Application (6)']

for s in arr:
 print(re.split(r'-\d+-', re.split(':', s)[0]))
```

Prints,

```
['ABC7', '1234']
['AB-WALT', '2065']
```

As an alternative way, you could also use this regex and capture your values from group1 and group2,

```
^(.+?)-\d+-([^:]+)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4TAbNN/1)**

Python code,

```
import re

arr = ['ABC7-8-1234: Veggie - RESTRICTED (1)', 'AB-WALT-9-2065: Application (6)']

for s in arr:
 m = re.search(r'^(.+?)-\d+-([^:]+)', s)
 if m:
  print([m.group(1), m.group(2)])
```

Prints,

```
['ABC7', '1234']
['AB-WALT', '2065']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex with non-capturing group (?:):

```
s1='ABC7-8-1234: Veggie - RESTRICTED (1)' 
re.split(r"(?:-\d)+",s1)                                               
Out: ['ABC7', '234: Veggie - RESTRICTED (1)']
```

Preserving the number from the separator pattern:

```
re.split(r"-(\d)",s1)                                                  
Out: ['ABC7', '8', '', '1', '234: Veggie - RESTRICTED (1)']
```

You get empty strings if there are consecutive patterns.

Using positive lookahead:

```
re.split(r"-(?=\d)",s1)                                                
Out: ['ABC7', '8', '1234: Veggie - RESTRICTED (1)']
```